# backbone.queryparams.js not working on IE

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to make an application work on IE, everything works fine until I try to use this backbone plugin: https://github.com/jhudson8/backbone-query-parameters.
It works fine on firefox or chrome, but whenever I try to use it along with IE throws the following error:
Object doesn't support this property or method   line 93 characer

```
rtn.paramNames = paramNames.map(function(name){
          return name.substring(1);
      }
  );
```

has anyone come up with this error or any aproach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Native `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) supports only from IE9.

To fix your issue just use [underscore map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) instead of native map:

```
rtn.paramNames = _.map(paramNames, function(name) {
  return name.substring(1);
});
```